# Connecting List and Library on SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, modern-experience, sitepages

I would like to connect a List and a Library in a way that when I select an item in the List, the Library will display files that have tags related to selected item. So let's say that I have a List added to the Page on the left, I'm selecting an item and the Library on the right displays all documents corresponding to this item.

I think it would be fairly easy to achieve on SP 2013. Thing is, I'm working on SPO and I have no idea where to start.

Can anyone give me some advices on that? Preferably in a simplest possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect list & document library web parts on modern SharePoint pages.

When you edit the web part, you can use **Dynamic filtering** option for SharePoint web parts.

**Example**:

[image]

Here I have used "ID" column to show as an example. But you can use the common columns in list & document library to filter files based on item selected in list web part.

---

Follow below documentation for more information: [Connect web parts in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec)